# represent list of dicts as a string

Tags: python, string, list

I have many lists of dictionaries with keys: origin/destination that I want to represent in a simpler and shorter way.

I was trying with some for loops and creating lists with the letters, but it has not worked for me.

Any idea how I could do this representation of the values?

Comment: Basically, make a dictionary of words to letters and use it to translate the input dictionaries.

Comment: What have you already tried, and what do you need help with exactly? Do you already know the process you'll need to follow to do this? It seems relatively straightforward to me, though I haven't attempted it yet. Please show us your best attempt. For more tips, see [ask]. You might also want to clarify the title.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? If you're trying to reduce space when saving the list in a file, you can use a compression command rather than your own encoding method.

Answer (score 0):

## I interpreted 3 answers from this:

### Introduction

All work regardless of list length

I believe the use of this is to have a dictionary without repeat values? (answer 3) but you use the term **list** a lot so it might be for readability to use? (answer 2). An individual dict for each? (Answer 1)

Is list 3 meant to be a-A, b-B not a-A, b-A?

lists is both lists together

```py
    list1 = [{'destination': '0390170374', 'origin': 'AR01'},
            {'destination': '0319399037', 'origin': 'AR01'},
            {'destination': '0350939840', 'origin': 'AR01'},
            {'destination': '0312087944', 'origin': 'AR01'},
            {'destination': '9054843126', 'origin': 'AR01'}]
    list2 = [{'destination': '331247128', 'origin': '00001'},
            {'destination': '354298982', 'origin': '00002'},
            {'destination': '354299148', 'origin': '00003'}]
    lists = [list1,list2]
```

## Answer 1

Changing the dictionary names to a, A.

### example

```py
{'a': '0390170374', 'A': 'AR01'}
{'b': '0319399037', 'B': 'AR01'}
```

### code

```py
def ansr1(lists):
    letterlist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e','f','g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    for list in lists:
        letter = 0
        amountofletters = 1
        for dict in list:
            if letter == 26:
                amountofletters += 1
                letter = 0
            else:
                print({str(letterlist[letter]*amountofletters): dict['destination'], str(letterlist[letter].capitalize()*amountofletters): dict['origin']})
                letter += 1
```

## Answer 2

Getting dictionary values and formatting them into a string, then appending to a list.

### example

```py
['0390170374-AR01', '0319399037-AR01', '0350939840-AR01', '0312087944-AR01', '9054843126-AR01']
```

### code

```py
def ansr2(lists):
    for list in lists:
        templist = []
        for dict in list:
            templist.append(f"{dict['destination']}-{dict['origin']}")
        else:
            print(templist)
```

## Answer 3

Changing the dictionary names to a, A, then appending to a dict

### example

```py
{'a': '0390170374', 'A': 'AR01', 'b': '0319399037', 'B': 'AR01', 'c': '0350939840', 'C': 'AR01', 'd': '0312087944', 'D': 'AR01', 'e': '9054843126', 'E': 'AR01'}
```

### code

```py
def ansr3(lists):
    letterlist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e','f','g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    for list in lists:
        letter = 0
        amountofletters = 1
        tempdict = {}
        for dict in list:
            if letter == 26:
                amountofletters += 1
                letter = 0
            else:
                tempdict[str(letterlist[letter]*amountofletters)] = (str(dict['destination']))
                tempdict[str(letterlist[letter].capitalize()*amountofletters)] = (str(dict['origin']))
                letter += 1
        else:
            print(tempdict)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is simply something that picks the next available value if not found.  Assuming you have less than 26 distinct origins and destinations, this would do it:

```
li = [{'destination': '0390170374', 'origin': 'AR01'},
 {'destination': '0319399037', 'origin': 'AR01'},
 {'destination': '0350939840', 'origin': 'AR01'},
 {'destination': '0312087944', 'origin': 'AR01'},
 {'destination': '9054843126', 'origin': 'AR01'}]

import string
ori,dst = {},{}

def get_sub(di, value, possibilities):
    res = di.get(value)
    if not res:
        res = di[value] = possibilities[len(di)]
    return res

def fmt(pair):
    return f"{get_sub(ori,pair['origin'],string.ascii_lowercase)}-{get_sub(dst,pair['destination'],string.ascii_uppercase)}"

li2 = [fmt(pair) for pair in li]
print(li2)
```

#### output:

```
['a-A', 'a-B', 'a-C', 'a-D', 'a-E']
```

That said, while intriguing, this seems of limited use.  A client program would not "know" what the encoded pairs corresponded to without having access to the 2 substitution dictionaries.  And you still have that 26 distinct value limit, unless you build something even more complicated.  Finally, your shorthand notation is not stable and what say `b-C` means will vary from run to run and even depends on the order of the incoming data.